# When I log in, display settings are reset

Tags: display-resolution, 22.04, acer

Last month, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Acer Nitro 5.
Every once in a while, when logging in, I notice my display settings are reset. The resolution is higher than I would like...

There's no warning message, when I log in. The only messages which are shown, are shown right at the start, just before the Acer logo is shown.

---

There are no files in `$HOME/.config/autostart/`
I'm using Nvidia driver metapackage 515 (proprietary and tested)

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the comment. There are no files on that directory...

Comment: Ok 2nd: what graphics driver is in use? does "additional drivers" offer others? and if so does switching fix it? Feel free to add it to the question instead of in comments. that way we can clean those up as we go. See  my edit :+

Comment: @Rinzwind I've just added it.